# Best practice of writing long equations using \begin{align*}

Tags: equations, vertical-alignment, align

## Problem

The compilation of the following code has two problems:

1. The equation starts from the second page not the first page.
2. The equation isn't printed completely. The page is finished before the equation is finished. There is no third page to include the remaining of the equation.
   [image]
   Code:

```
\documentclass[17pt]{extreport}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
&rho*fvm::d2dt2(u)\\
&-fvm::laplacian(k,u)\\
&-fvc::div(sigma-k*grad(u))\\
&=rho*f\\
Then:\\
&rho*fvm::d2dt2(u)\\
&-fvm::laplacian(k,u)\\
&-fvc::div(sigma)\\
&+fvc::div(k*grad(u))\\
&=rho*f\\
Then:\\
&rho*fvm::d2dt2(u)\\
&-fvm::laplacian(k,u)\\
&-fvc::div(sigma)\\
&+fvc::div(k*grad(u))\\
&+fvc::laplacian(k,u)\\
&-fvc::laplacian(k,u)\\
&=rho*f\\
Then:\\
&rho*fvm::d2dt2(u)\\
&-fvm::laplacian(k,u)\\
&+fvc::laplacian(k,u)\\
&-fvc::div(sigma)\\
&+fvc::div(k*grad(u))\\
&-fvc::laplacian(k,u)\\
&=rho*f\\
\end{align*} 


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Do not do never-ending equations. Change each line `Then: \\ `   by `\end{align*} Then:  \begin{align*}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide the instruction `\allowdisplaybreaks` to give permission to LaTeX to insert a pagebreak somewhere in the long `align*` environment.

I would also attempt to provide more visual "rhythm", say by not aligning all rows on the exact same (vertical) line. I would also like to suggest that the `Then:` statements be taken out of the equation by placing them in `\shortintertext` statements.

A final remark: I assume you know what you're doing by using a math-italic font (not even a text-italic font shape) for virtually the entire body of the `align*` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass[17pt]{extreport}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry}  % set suitable page parameters
\usepackage{mathtools}
\allowdisplaybreaks
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
&rho*fvm::d2dt2(u)\\
&\quad-fvm::laplacian(k,u)\\
&\quad-fvc::div(sigma-k*grad(u))\\
&\qquad= rho*f\\
\shortintertext{Then:}
&rho*fvm::d2dt2(u)\\
&\quad-fvm::laplacian(k,u)\\
&\quad-fvc::div(sigma)\\
&\quad+fvc::div(k*grad(u))\\
&\qquad= rho*f\\
\shortintertext{Then:}
&rho*fvm::d2dt2(u)\\
&\quad-fvm::laplacian(k,u)\\
&\quad-fvc::div(sigma)\\
&\quad+fvc::div(k*grad(u))\\
&\quad+fvc::laplacian(k,u)\\
&\quad-fvc::laplacian(k,u)\\
&\qquad= rho*f\\
\shortintertext{Then:}
&rho*fvm::d2dt2(u)\\
&\quad-fvm::laplacian(k,u)\\
&\quad+fvc::laplacian(k,u)\\
&\quad-fvc::div(sigma)\\
&\quad+fvc::div(k*grad(u))\\
&\quad-fvc::laplacian(k,u)\\
&\qquad= rho*f\\
\end{align*} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: When `\allowdisplaybreaks` is in effect, "starring" the double backslash -- `\\*` -- can be used to prevent a break after selected lines.

Comment: Is it possible to use `\texttt` or alike typeface in `align*` environment?

Comment: @Alish - Absolutely. I would actually recommend a two-stage approach. First, wrap all instances of `fvm`,. `fvc`, `laplacian`, etc. in `\vn` wrappers (e.g., `\vn{fvm}`, etc). ("vn" stands for "variable name".) Second, define `\vn` via `\newcommand\vn[1]{\textit{#1}}`. This gives you a very useful degree of freemom: if you ever decide that you would prefer a monospaced font for the variable names, say, all you'd have to change is the definition of `\vn` to, say, `\newcommand\vn[1]{\texttt{#1}}`